# Getting error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sender') " once I put equal to or less than operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chat

```
export const isSameSender = (
  messages: any[],
  message: any,
  index: number,
  user: IUser
) => {
  return (
   //if I put just "<" instead of "<=" in the below line, there's no error
    index <= messages.length - 1 &&
    messages[index + 1].sender._id === message.sender._id && //this line gives that error
    messages[index].sender._id !== user._id
  )
}

export const isLastMessage = (messages: any[], index: number, user: IUser) => {
  return index <= messages.length - 1 && messages[index].sender._id !== user._id
}
```

I feel if I haven't been able to understand && properly but why does puttting <= instead of < gives the error, I am trying to check if the messages array has reached it's final index to check if it has finished looping but as soon as I use <=  in this code the second code gives the error, I don't know why.

Can anyone enlighten me on what's happening? If giving `any[]` as a type to the messages array is causing this problem?

Comment: if `index == messages.length - 1` then `messages[index + 1]` will be `undefined` since that index is one higher than the greatest index in `messages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because if `index` is actually equal to `messages.length - 1`, then

`messages[index + 1]` is undefined because `messages[messages.length - 1 + 1]` which means `messages[messages.length]`, so `undefined` because there is not such index in the `messages` array.

Comment: Didn't notice it, thanks!